# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow on python 3.7, Ubuntu 16.04. The code which throws the above mentioned error is written below. It is based on the following [code](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func). I am getting this error on both tensorflow 1.13 as well as 2.0.0-beta1

I have a dataset folder containing millions of data pair of the form (image,timeseries). The timeseries is in numpy format. I want to use np.load() function to load the data. But the filename is in string tensor format. The problem is np.load() does not accept tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import imageio

#tf.enable_eager_execution()    # use this line if using tensorflow 1.13

imageio.imwrite('data.jpg', np.random.rand(256,256,3))
np.save('data.npy',np.ones(1024))

def load(image_file,timeseries_file):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
    timeseries = np.load(timeseries_file.decode())
    timeseries = tf.convert_to_tensor(timeseries, np.float32)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    timeseries = tf.cast(timeseries, tf.float32)
    return image, timeseries

image_files = ['data.jpg']
timeseries_files = ['data.npy']
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_files, timeseries_files))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
lambda image_file, timeseries_file: tuple(tf.py_function(
    load, [image_file, timeseries_file], [tf.float32, tf.float32])))
for x in train_dataset.take(1):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

EagerTensor can be converted to numpy array as:

```
tensor.numpy()
# or
np.array(tensor)
```

So try:

```
timeseries = np.load(timeseries_file.numpy().decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf 
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Comment: Some explanation how and why this solves the error would be really helpful.

Comment: In tf 2.0 the eager execution is enabled by default, hence disabling v2 behaviour disables the eager execution. [More on eager execution.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)